# Asp.net Session Expire soon on live Web server

Tags: asp.net, live

I am facing a problem about web application,

I have lost session too soon

, I have already set timeout and that related things.

it is done when I have uploaded it on

> LIVE SERVER

, after spend some time I not able to use session, it redirect me on Login.

Please tell me what i can do?

Thanks

Comment: Check app-Pool idle timeout if you are using In-Proc session state, Your app-pool recycling can cause session loss .

Comment: have you checked timeout setting for authentication? if you have set that too low, it will also redirect you to Login page

Comment: Yes @Laurence Nyein, I have checked timeout, and Increased as much as we can set.

Comment: @Suraj Singh, I am facing this problem on LIVE Server, Please tell me How can i check their app-pool setting? on local it is working fine.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry i have to reply as answer not comment ,

Type **“inetmgr”** in run window to open `IIS` 
from left pane “**Connections**” select your application. 
right click on your application and refer the image to open `“Advanced Settings”` of application(to check which `ApplicationPool` is referred by application )

from `“Application Settings”` window you can see the Name of ApplicationPool. like `Asp.net V4.0`, `DefaultAppPool`, `Asp.net V4.0 Classic`.

Right click on the ApplicationPool that was assigned to your Application and click on "`Advanced Settings`...."

in the popup window ... check the `Idle time out` for ... that cause the timeout while web application is idle.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @suraj!! I need to ask that is it eork on my live server too? I am using this one http://www.parallels.com/

Comment: @RIYAZ This is just a guess that may be this is causing you problem so you can give it a try , If idle time is less than it will overrule your webconfig timeout setting , So just give it a try

Comment: Okay, Thanks @suraj!! I'll let you know surely

Comment: But, the problem was related to a server than he could not manipulate the iis

Answer (score 0):

There're multiple ways why ASP.NET session state can be lost. The most common one is when the application pool recycles. This, in turn, can be due to IIS configuration (scheduled recycles), changes to the `/bin` folder or `web.config` file (can also be an anti-virus software that "touches" the files).

In case the session state is maintained using cookies, there can be situations when the browser doesn't accept them (and therefore, doesn't pass them back resulting in a new session created every time). You can verify that the cookies are sent (and that the value is not changing within the same session) by using Fiddler or F12 tools of your choice (the name of the cookie is `ASP.NET_SessionId`).

You may also check the `sessionState` configuration element in your `web.config` file to make sure those settings are correct (more on the subject: [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

Also, check the Event Log ("Application" log where the "Source" would be "ASP.NET X.X.X.X" where "X.X.X.X" is the framework version). In cases like this, there's usually some useful information in there.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, **volpav** to writing for me, but I have done all things you mentioned, on my local **IIS** it is working fine but after hosted on **Live server** facing this problem

Answer (score 0):

All servers/hosting have a configuration environment, obviously if your problem passes in dev you need to solve it there, but if is only happening in the server maybe could be for server configuration from your provider, for example, almost all providers by default when you create an application from Plesk set timeout on session for 20 minutes, so, that's could be the problem of anybody than have the same issue.