# session timeout url parameter

Tags: asp-classic, session-timeout

I use session cookies as part of a user login system. My problem is that sometimes my users are being locked out "before time" (standard timeout is 20 minutes).
My question is rather simple, but I have not been able to find the answer anywhere on the internet:
After login the user is send to default.asp and stay there for 10 minutes. He moves to default.asp?id=23 for 5 minutes. He then goes to default.asp?id=45. Can he now go to default.asp?id=10 after 15 minutes?
In other words: Does the timeout time reset when the url parameter id is changed or does he have to move move to a totally new url ex. contact.asp?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no, it doesn't matter. 
Session timeout is recalculated after each browser request.

Read this for possible solutions: [Asp.net Session Expire soon on live Web server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19311649/asp-net-session-expire-soon-on-live-web-server)

Answer (score 0):

The timeout resets to 0 by going to any URL. It doesn't matter if ID is changing or complete page address.